# Problema en la instalación dependencias npm en proyecto descargado con .gitignore en mac usando visual studio

Tags: nodejs, vscode, npm, macos, gitignore

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]No encuentro en ningun lado casos concretos de como poder instalar las dependencias mediante npm, al salir el error 127 una vez ejecutado el comando npm install.
Gracias y un saludo

Comment: ¿Y el problema? Muestra _como texto, con formato_ la salida que estás obteniendo. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Bueno formulado en pregunta, ¿porqué en windows npm install funciona sin problemas en un proyecto existente, mientras en macOs no me instala las dependencias? es decir, el problema reside en que intenta crear node_module, pero al finalizar en la terminal sale error 127. No se si es un problema de permisos, del .gitignore presente en el proyecto o versión de node.

Comment: Por si sirve de algo, la versión de npm 8.11.0 y node v16.15.1

Answer (score 0):

El problema se debe a que alguna de las dependencias de npm del proyecto requiere la compilación de extensiones nativas para Node.js, y para ello requiere [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp). En el repositorio se encuentra una guía de instalación para macOS, la instalación se realiza con `npm install -g node-gyp`, sin embargo, para su instalación se requiere que las herramientas de línea de comandos de Xcode estén instaladas en el sistema.

Edit: El comando que en realidad se está usando es `node-pre-gyp`, el cual puede obtenerse del paquete `@mapbox/node-pre-gyp`, instalándose con `npm install -g @mapbox/node-pre-gyp`.

Comment: De acuerdo muchas gracias, probaré con esta solución

Comment: Basicamente si puede ayudar en futuro, el problema estaba en una dependencia no suportada,  "color-thief-node": "^1.0.4", con eliminar esta en el package.json y eliminando el package-lock.json se ha resuelto el problema.